# play media from download in progress

Tags: stream, download, afnetworking, audio-streaming

i'm using AFNetworking to download media files. Audio and Video. I use AFDownloadRequestOperation to get a better way to pause and resume large downloads.

i found lots of tutorials for download and for stream media but i need a way to start download and play the unfinished download from disk to get a better experience while playing large files.

does anybody know how to do this?

As Player i use AVPlayer with AVPlayerItem and AVAsset

if there is another way without this 3 Objects it would be great.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: not yet but I'm trying different options

Comment: Please let me know if you succeed :)